# Error in dplyr function

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

```
form_name = [1] "abc.A"    "abc.A.1"  "abc.B"    "abc.B.1"  "abc.DR"   "abc.DR.1"

library(dplyr)
dd <- list(NULL)
for(i in form_name){
dd[[i]] <- ka %>% group_by(i) %>% summarise(n= n())
}
```

When i apply loop over dplyr function it says

> Error: unknown column 'i'

Comment: Where is `ka` defined ?

Comment: @Amstell ka is a data frame which has rownames which is stored in **form_name**

Comment: actually i want to group by columns each time. I have 6 columns , so i applied loop

Comment: @Amstell group_by_(.dots=i) is not working the way i want to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `group_by_(.dots=i)`.  We create a `NULL` list ('dd') and set the `names` as 'form_name', then loop through the 'form_name', and change the `group_by` as mentioned above.

```
dd <- setNames(vector('list', length= length(form_name)), form_name)
for(i in form_name){
  dd[[i]] <- ka %>%
                 group_by_(.dots=i) %>%
                 summarise(n=n())
}

dd
#$abc.A
#Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

#   abc.A     n
#  (fctr) (int)
#1      A     2
#2      B     2
#3      C     2

#$abc.B
#Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

#   abc.B     n
#  (fctr) (int)
#1      D     3
#2      E     3
```

#### data

```
form_name <- c('abc.A', 'abc.B')
ka <- data.frame(abc.A= rep(LETTERS[1:3], 2), 
                   abc.B= rep(LETTERS[4:5], each=3))
```

Comment: The above function summarise only the total number of elements. let say in one column abc.A i have "101"  "120"  "111"  "101"  "1010".  the above function will show n = 5 . while i want the contingency table as how many time each number is repeated

Comment: @DhwaniDholakia  Please check it carefully.  This is what your code does.

Comment: i am not aware hoe to post table in this forum, else i could have actually posted the table and its result

Comment: @DhwaniDholakia  If you have loaded plyr library along with `dplyr`, use `dplyr::summarise(`

Comment: the edited above explanations is very informative. I will try doing things one again

Comment: $HLA.A
   Source: local data frame [25 x 2]

   HLA.A     n  <br/>
   (fctr) (int)   
1             4
2     101    23  
3    1101    30  
4     143     1  
5     201     9  
6     203     2
7     205     4
8     206     3
9     211     7
10   2314     1
..    ...   ...                    . i am not able to view after 10 rows. how to view that

Comment: how to view the last rows . it shows only upto 10 rows

Comment: @DhwaniDholakia  You can use `lapply(dd, as.data.frame)` or `lapply(dd, function(x) head(x, 20))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99581/discussion-between-dhwani-dholakia-and-akrun).